# Persisting Doctrine relationship, Argument 1 passed to ..\ArrayCollection::__construct() must be of the type array

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm setting up a One-to-Many unidirectional relationship with a join table, as described here: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table

I have an entity called TestEntity and an entity called testOptionalProperty.  When I try to persist my Entity object, I get the error

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection::__construct() must be of
>   the type array, object given, called in
>   /Users/dave/Desktop/doctrine-fun/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php
>   on line 555 and defined

Here are my entities:

TestEntity.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * TestEntity
 */
class TestEntity
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;

    private $testOptionalProperty;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTestOptionalProperty()
    {
        return $this->testOptionalProperty;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $testOptionalProperty
     */
    public function setTestOptionalProperty($testOptionalProperty)
    {
        $this->testOptionalProperty = $testOptionalProperty;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return TestEntity
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

TestOptionalProperty.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * TestOptionalProperty
 */
class TestOptionalProperty
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $value;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set value
     *
     * @param integer $value
     * @return TestOptionalProperty
     */
    public function setValue($value)
    {
        $this->value = $value;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get value
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getValue()
    {
        return $this->value;
    }
}
```

Controller Method:

```
public function testAction()
{
    $entity = new TestEntity();
    $entity->setName('Testing');
    $entity->setTestOptionalProperty(new TestOptionalProperty());
    $entity->getTestOptionalProperty()->setValue(100);
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush();
}
```

And my doctrine mapping:

```
AppBundle\Entity\TestEntity:
    type: entity
    table: null
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 255
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
    manyToMany:
            testOptionalProperty:
                targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\TestOptionalProperty
                cascade: ["persist"]
                joinTable:
                    name: entity_property
                    joinColumns:
                        entity_id:
                            referencedColumnName: id
                            unique: true
                    inverseJoinColumns:
                        property_id:
                            referencedColumnName: id


AppBundle\Entity\TestOptionalProperty:
    type: entity
    table: null
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        value:
            type: integer
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Comment: Your mappings are seriously messed up. Consult the docs: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html.  OneToMany relations will not have join tables.

Comment: In the link I provided at the top of my question, I link to the doctrine documentation explaining the exact mapping that I am trying to use. It is a one to many unidirectional with a join table

Comment: OneToMany relations do not have join tables.  Your orm file shows a ManyToMany relation.  If you really want a ManyToMany relation with additional relations on the join table then make an entity specifically for the join table and break the ManyToMany into two ManyToOne relations.

Comment: Please read the link I provided at the top of my question. I am setting my entities up exactly like the doctorine documentation describes.

Comment: So why isn't testOptionalProperty an array Like the documentation shows and what the error message indicates?

Comment: Thank you! I was reading the yaml documentation and completely missed that part in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Is simple, the `ArrayCollection` `__construct` get only an `Array` as parameter, because you try to persist an `ManyToMany` relationship you need to encapsulate the object in an array `$array[] = $object;` otherwise change the relationship between the entities in a `OneToOne`.

Btw, try to run `app/console doctrine:generate:entities VendorAppBundle:TestEntity` for generating relation-based getters and setters

Comment: But it's not a one-to-one relationship.